# Algorithm of choosing the way

Tags: algorithm

I have an interesing problem to share with you.
Let's assume you're driving a car and you stumble upon a crossroads with 3 possible ways to choose. 
You are in need of gas and you need to find a gas station, but there is only one gas station in one of the directions.
The task is to find an algorithm of finding the gas station. BUT, assuming x is the distance between the gas station and the crossroads, the total distance you drive has to be a LINEAR function of x.

This has been running my mind for hours now, any ideas? :)

EDIT: You do not know x at the beginning!

Comment: Do you know `x` in advance? If not then this could be an interesting problem.

Comment: The informed choice: Turn around and drive back to where you're coming from and where you know where a gas station is.

Comment: @interjay of course not, I wouldn't post it otherwise :) edited the post

Comment: Have you a kind of map which you can drive virtually, and then make a decision? For example. You are in a cross, use your GPS and it find the nearest GAS station and calculate the shortest path. Translated: It uses a BFS ( breadth-first-serach ) then Dijkstra ( shortest-path ), you drive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drive 1 km in one direction, then go back. Then drive 2 km in another direction and go back. Then 4, 8, 16, etc. Continue until you find the gas station.

If the gas station was between 2^n and 2^(n+1) km away, you will drive a total of no more than

```
S = 2 * (1+2+4+...+2^(n+3)).
```

So, `S < 2 * 2^(n+4) < 32 * 2^n < 32x` (because `x > 2^n`). So will will have driven less than `32x` km.

Comment: Why is it 4, 8, 16, 32, etc and not 2, 4, 6, 8?

Comment: @user3035880: because that sum would lead to quadratic behaviour.

Comment: @user3035880 Because 1+2+4+8+16+...+2^n is less than 2^(n+1), which is a linear function of the last distance traveled. On the other hand, 2+4+6+8+...+2n = n*(n+1) is a quadratic function of the last distance